# send option from dialog menu to edit Text in android

Tags: android

How can If I Click any option in this Dialog menu send that option to edit text?

```
   private void openPlacesDialog() {
        // Ask the user to choose the place where they are now.
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // The "which" argument contains the position of the selected item.
                LatLng markerLatLng = mLikelyPlaceLatLngs[which];
                String markerSnippet = mLikelyPlaceAddresses[which];

                if (mLikelyPlaceAttributions[which] != null) {
                    markerSnippet = markerSnippet + "\n" + mLikelyPlaceAttributions[which];
                }
``
```

Comment: Use Interface as you use for fragment to activity communication

Comment: What is the problem, exactly? That is, why can't you just call `editText.setText(markerSnippet);` there?

Comment: @MikeM. Thank you brother / This is my first project. I am new, so my mistake was as follows `lonTextView.setText(mLikelyPlaceAddresses.toString());`

Comment: @MikeM.It works now thanks

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela Thank you brother

Comment: @MikeM. It works now and I can get LatLng but there are now one problem the LatLng it's coming like that (lat/lng:38.64739,35.127484) so the two  latitude and longitude coning into one line ..how can just select one for example just select (longitude)?

Comment: If that's the Google Maps `LatLng` class, then those are both fields in it. That is, to get just the longitude, it would be simply `markerLatLng.longitude`. That's only the numeric value, however, so if you want `"lng"` in front of it, you'll have to concatenate it yourself; e.g., `String longitude = "lng: " + markerLatLng.longitude;`.

Comment: @MikeM. You are the best brother .. it is clear and works thank you